# Process responsible for screen rotation / orientation sensor?

Tags: lenovo, screen, orientation

What's the process called that's responsible for managing auto-screen rotation (sensor?)  and is there a way to disable it or bind it to a specific hardware button (let's say the power button)?

I am currently using lenovo yoga-pad-2

Comment: binding it to power button will not be recommended.  what device you are using and what is the version of the ubuntu you have installed

Comment: Currently using a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 2 Pro. Would like to disable auto-rotation.